# Meta boxes not showing on custom post type. Blank page?

Tags: metabox

I am working on my first plugin. I've got a custom post type, with a meta box which has 4 fields which uses update_post_meta, & these work 100% fine. I have then tried to create a meta box that  has repeatable fields, when the user clicks 'add new field'. I want users to be able to add as many fields as they like.

My Question: Below, is my code to add new fields. This just doesn't display in the custom post type when viewed, but I don't get any errors. Please can you have a look at my code below, & advise?

```
<?php
// START OF CREATE MORE META BOXES AS NEEDED INCLUDING JQUERY 
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'dynamic_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamic_save_postmeta' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the post and page edit screens */

function dynamic_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box(
            'dynamic_sectionid', 'My Tracks', 'mp_myplugin_textdomain', 'mp_dynamic_inner_custom_box', 'post' );
}

/* Prints the box content  */

function mp_dynamic_inner_custom_box() {
    global $post;
    ?> 
    <div id="meta_inner"> 
        <?php
        // get the saved meta as an array 
        $mpformfield = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mpformfield', true );
        $c = 0;
        if ( count( $mpformfield ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $mpformfield as $mpfield ) {
                if ( isset( $mpfield['name'] ) ) {
                    printf( '<p> Field Name <input type="text" name="fieldname[%1$s][name]" value="%2$s" /> <br /> </p>' );
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <span id="here"></span> 
        <span class="add"><?php 'Add form field'; ?> </span> 
        <script>  
            var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                var count =  <?php echo $c; ?>; 
                $(".add").click(function() { 
                    count = count + 1; 

                    $('#here').append('<p> Form field <input type="text" name="fieldname['+count+'][name]"  value="" /><span class="remove"> Remove form field </span>  </p>'); 
                    return false; 
                }); 
                $(".remove").live('click', function() { 
                    $(this).parent().remove(); 
                }); 
            }); 
        </script>
    </div> <?php
}

/* when the post is saved, saves our custom data */

function dynamic_save_postmeta( $post_id ) {
    // verify if this is an auto save routine 
    // if it is our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything 
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // Save the data 
    $mpformfield = $_POST['mpformfield'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mpformfield', $mpformfield );
}
```

Comment: Your code is full of break tags. Please clean it up.

Comment: @vancoder Realised straight away, & just finished cleaning it up. Thanks for taking an interest!

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting javascript errors?

Comment: @vancoder  There are javascript errors (that's how much of a rookie I am) . Thank-you!!

Comment: You are adding the meta box only to the `post` post type. You need one `add_meta_box` per post type. What do you mean by "blank page", it is simply that the meta box doesn't show up or the code breaks the site and you have a blank screen when trying to access the page? The concept of "repeatable meta boxes" is not correct, what you can have are repeatable fields inside a meta box. Check [this search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2badd_meta_box%20%2bsave_post%20is%3aanswer) for many working examples.

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks for taking an interest. The meta box doesn't show up. I'll correct my question above, so that it refers to repeatable fields. Sorry, but what do you mean by 'you are adding the meta box only to the post type'? I'm new to wordpress development & slightly confused by what you've said.

Comment: @brasofilo Can I only use add_meta_box once, for each post type? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a meta box to multiple post types, one `add_meta_box` per post type is needed. In this example, instead of duplicating the same code, a `foreach` is used. More post types can be added to the array and the meta box will be added in all of them:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_box_wpse_94701' );

function add_custom_box_wpse_94701() 
{
    // Post types to insert the meta box. Adjust array <-------
    foreach( array( 'post', 'portfolio' ) as $pt )
        add_meta_box(
            'sectionid_wpse_94701',
            __( 'Custom parent' ), 
            'blogroll_box_wpse_94701',
            $pt,
            'side'
        );
}
```

The example above is taken from this Q&A: [List of Posts in a Custom Field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/94701/12615)

Note that the action hook `save_post` takes 2 parameters, `$post_id` and `$post_object`. The latter contains all the post data (title, content, post type, etc).

There are other checks that can be done inside `save_post`. Check [this search query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2badd_meta_box%20%2bsave_post%20is%3aanswer) for examples of adding meta boxes and saving the post data.